# You and your friend are each dealt two cards: hers face up and yours face down. Which of the following scenarios are you more likely to have a pair?

Tags: probability, card-games

I am self-teaching probability, could someone please help me determine if I've solved this problem correctly, as I don't have the answers to these exercises.

The following question is taken from Dennis Sun's Probability course at Cal Poly SLO: "You and your friend Amy are each dealt two cards: hers face up and yours face down. In which of the following scenarios are you more likely to have a pair: 1) When she has a pair of Queens, 2) Or when she has a Queen and a 5?" https://dlsun.github.io/probability/conditional.html

I modeled this the same way as if I were drawing 4 cards. Let A be the statement: I have a pair. B: Amy has Queens. C: Amy has Q5

I calculated the prior probability that Amy has Queens as $$P(B) = {{4 \choose 2}\over{52 \choose 2}} = 0.00452$$ And the prior that she has Q5 as: $$P(C) = {{4 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}\over{52 \choose 2}} = 0.0121$$Then the probability that Amy has Queens and I have a pair is
$$P(AB) = {{4 \choose 4} + {4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}\over{52 \choose 4}} = 0.00160$$
where the 1st term in the numerator is the ways that she can have Queens and I have the other 2 queens, and the 2nd term is the ways that she can have Queens and I have any other pair. Then the conditional probability would be: $$ P(A|B) = {{P(AB)}\over{P(B)}} = .353$$ And the probability that Amy has Q5 and I have a pair is
$$P(AB) = {{4 \choose 1}{4 \choose 3}\cdot2 + {4 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}\over{52 \choose 4}} = 0.00402$$ where the 1st term in the numerator is the probability that I have 5's or Q's. And the 2nd term is I have any other pair.

And the conditional probability would be: $$ P(A|C) = {{P(AC)}\over{P(C)}} = .333$$

Did I make a mistake? It seems strange that the probability of me making a pair would go down if she has Q5.

Comment: You cannot model this as drawing a set of 4 cards without ordering (e.g. $\binom{52}{4}$ in the denominator) because you need to distinguish which cards belong to Amy and which cards belong to you.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you for the reply, I will take another look at it!

Comment: Don't forget to apply the same principle to the numerator too.  @Azimuth

Comment: @angryavian Yes that was a huge error, I see now that obviously a pair cannot be formed between 2 separate hands. Among other weird errors I made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your probability of having a pair does in fact decrease if Amy has Q5, rather than QQ.

The easiest way to stretch your intuition around this is to assume that you are playing with an $8$ card deck, $4$ Q's and $4$ 5's.

Then, if Amy has a Q5, the number of ways that you can have a pair are $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{1} = 6. ~$  That is,
there are $3$ ways of forming a pair with the three remaining 5's, and so on.

If Amy has QQ, then the number of ways that you can have a pair are $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{2} = 7.$

So, Amy's having paired up has increased your chances.

---

With the specific problem around a 52 card deck, you are confused about how to use [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Let $E_1$ denote the event that Amy has Q5.
Let $E_2$ denote the event that Amy has QQ.
Let $E_3$ denote the event that you have a pair.

In effect, you are being asked to compute and compare 
$p(E_3|E_1)$ versus $p(E_3|E_2)$.

From the intuition stretching in the first part of the answer, you should expect that $p(E_3|E_2)$ will be **slightly** larger than $p(E_3|E_1).$

You know that in general, $~\displaystyle p(R|S) = \frac{p(R,S)}{p(S)}.$  Here, I use the syntax $(R,S)$ to denote that events $R$ and $S$ both occur.

So, you will need to compute:

$$p(E_3|E_1) = \frac{p(E_1,E_3)}{p(E_1)} \tag1 $$

and

$$p(E_3|E_2) = \frac{p(E_2,E_3)}{p(E_2)}. \tag2 $$

---

Problems like these are best attacked combinatorically, where the probability is expressed as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

$\displaystyle p(E_1) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}.$

The easiest way to determine $p(E_1,E_3)$ is to *reason it out*.  With a Q5 given to Amy, there are

$\displaystyle \left[11 \times \binom{4}{2}\right] + \left[2 \times \binom{3}{2}\right] = 72$ different ways that your cards may be paired up.  The $(11)$ refers to the $(11)$ ranks other than Q or 5, and the $(2)$ represents the Q and 5 ranks.

So, $\displaystyle p(E_1,E_3) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{4}{1} \times 72}{\binom{52}{2} \times \binom{50}{2}}.$

In the above expression, the denominator represents that first there are $\binom{52}{2}$ ways that Amy is dealt two cards, and then $\binom{50}{2}$ ways that you are dealt two cards from the remaining cards in the deck.

Putting this all together, you have that

$$p(E_3|E_1) = \frac{p(E_1,E_3)}{p(E_1)}$$

$$= \frac{\frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{4}{1} \times 72}{\binom{52}{2} \times \binom{50}{2}}}{\frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}}
$$

$$= \frac{72}{\binom{50}{2}}. \tag3 $$

---

The Mathematics around $~\displaystyle \frac{p(E_2,E_3)}{p(E_2)}~$ will be very similar.

$\displaystyle p(E_2) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}.$

The easiest way to determine $p(E_2,E_3)$ is to *reason it out*.  With a QQ given to Amy, there are

$\displaystyle \left[12 \times \binom{4}{2}\right] + \left[1 \times \binom{2}{2}\right] = 73$ different ways that your cards may be paired up.  The $(12)$ refers to the $(12)$ ranks other than Q, and the $(1)$ represents the Q rank.

So, $\displaystyle p(E_2,E_3) = \frac{\binom{4}{2} \times 73}{\binom{52}{2} \times \binom{50}{2}}.$

Putting this all together, you have that

$$p(E_3|E_2) = \frac{p(E_2,E_3)}{p(E_2)}$$

$$= \frac{\frac{\binom{4}{2}\times 73}{\binom{52}{2} \times \binom{50}{2}}}{\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}}
$$

$$= \frac{73}{\binom{50}{2}}. \tag4 $$

So, as expected,

$$p(E_3|E_1) = \frac{72}{\binom{50}{2}} ~~\text{and}~~ p(E_3|E_2) = \frac{73}{\binom{50}{2}}.$$

Comment: Hugely appreciate the detailed answer! This was my first kind of problem like this and I've really been struggling. It all makes sense now though. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 3):

In either case, there are $50$ cards left in the deck and $\binom{50}{2}$ sets of $2$ cards you can draw, all of which we assume are equally likely.  It only remains to count the number of two-card sets which are pairs in the two cases.

Case 1: Amy has drawn a pair of Queens.  In this case, the number of pairs left in the deck is
$$12 \binom{4}{2} + 1 \binom{2}{2} = 73$$
Case 2: Amy has drawn a Queen and a Five.  The number of pairs left in the deck is
$$11 \binom{4}{2} + 2 \binom{3}{2} = 72$$
So your chance of drawing a pair is higher in the first case, in which Amy has drawn a pair of Queens.  If you want to know the probabilities involved, divide the number of favorable cases by $\binom{50}{2}$.

Comment: Really appreciate the reply! Cool problem, I am just barely getting used to these.